How to display dictionary in a Table?
I want to display a dictionary in a SwiftUI Table like shown below. But unlike List, Table doesn't have an id parameter, so the compiler reports an error:

Type 'Dictionary<String, String>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: String)') cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

@State var dic: [String : String] = [
    "name" : "Tim",
    "company" : "Apple"
]

Table(dic.map{$0}.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }) {
    TableColumn("Name") { item in
        Text(item.key)
    }
    TableColumn("Value") { item in
        TextField("", text: $item.value)
    }
}

So the problem is how to makes the tuple here conform to Identifiable?

What are the table's columns and rows? Is it going to have two columns - "Key" and "Value"? And each key-value pair in the dictionary is a table row? Is that what you want?

I'd just make an identifiable wrapper type that wraps the tuple. You are already sorting the dictionary anyway, adding a map to transform the tuples into your own type is not much worse.

Maybe you are better of with a List with for instance a LabeledContent component for each row (key/value pair).

The Dictionary type in Swift is unordered, and so is not a good fit for populating a Table.
I suggest converting your Dictionary into an Array of structs that conform to the Identifiable protocol.
I would suggest doing that when you initialize your view model rather than sorting your Dictionary "live" when building your Table. Sorting is a somewhat slow process.
